# Show filter on cms page

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have a cms page, where custom collection is displayed. I want to add filter to this page.

Magento version: EE 1.14.2.4

contents of my cms page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" template="template.phtml"}}
```

in a template.phtml tried this code

```
$filter = new Enterprise_Search_Block_Catalog_Layer_View();
echo $filter->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml();
```

but getting error

```
Varien_Exception: Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::toHtml(Array())
```

How can I add filter to my cms page?

I need a page, where a custom collection and a filter will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$filter = new Enterprise_Search_Block_Catalog_Layer_View();
$filter->setLayout(Mage::app()->getLayout());
echo $filter->setTemplate('catalog/layer/view.phtml')->toHtml();
```